# How could one plot 3D matrix in 2D?

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am new in coding with `matlab`. I have the following 3D matrix

```
>> Xc
Xc(:,:,1) =

   -1.6803   -1.6803   -1.6803   -1.6803        
   -1.1803   -1.1803   -1.1803   -1.1803         
   -0.6803   -0.6803   -0.6803   -0.6803        
  -14.1803  -14.1803  -14.1803  -14.1803         
Xc(:,:,2) =

   -1.6803   -1.6803   -1.6803   -1.6803         
   -1.1803   -1.1803   -1.1803   -1.1803         
   -0.6803   -0.6803   -0.6803   -0.6803        
  -14.1803  -14.1803  -14.1803  -14.1803         
.
.
.
.
Xc(:,:,64) =

   -7.5112   -7.5112   -7.5112   -7.5112         
   -4.8926   -4.8926   -4.8926   -4.8926         
   -0.0081   -0.0081   -0.0081   -0.0081         
  -13.7577  -13.7577  -13.7577  -13.7577
```

how can I plot the first column of all these 64 pieces in a heat map sort of plot parallel to each others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To plot slices along the second dimension in 3D

You can do that with the [`slice`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html) function. Note that this function generates `surface` objects (like `surf` does), in which the *row* index corresponds to the *y* axis and the *column* index to the *x* axis. So the first two coordinates in `Xc` have to be swapped with [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
[ii, jj, kk] = ndgrid(-2:.5:2, -2:.8:2, -2:.4:2);
Xc = jj.*exp(-ii.^2-jj.^2-kk.^2); % example adapted from `slice` documentation
slice(permute(Xc, [2 1 3]), [], 1:size(Xc,2), [])
xlabel row, ylabel column, zlabel page
view(67, 31)
colorbar
```

[image]

### To plot a single slice along the second dimension in 2D

It suffices to index `Xc` in the second dimension, squeeze into a matrix with `permute`, and use [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html):

```
column_index = 4;
imagesc(permute(Xc(:, column_index, :), [1 3 2]))
```

[image]

Comment: I already plotted the data with slice. I want to get it in 2D space since the columns in each slice are similar.

Comment: @Dalek I don't get what you mean. But whatever that is, that info should have been in the challenge from the beginning, so potential answer writers do not waste their time

Comment: The columns in each slice of my data set are similar and there is waste of space and noninformative piece of information to plot all matrix. I would like to plot in 64 back to back columns the first column of each slice.

Comment: I'd like to plot Xc(:,1,:) in the format of a heatmap figure.

Comment: @Dalek Just that? Then try `imagesc(permute(Xc(:,1,:), [1 3 2]))`